# Enhancement of Mobile Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu which contains submenu and then each sub menu item contains some other sub menus. Something like this:

```
<div class="mobile-menu-wrapper">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        Item 2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>sub-item 1</li>
            <li>sub-item 2</li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                sub-item 3
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>sub-sub-item 1</li>
                    <li>sub-sub-item 2</li>
                    <li>sub-sub-item 3</li>
                    <li>sub-sub-item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>sub-item 4</li>
            <li>sub-item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this is how my JavaScript looks like

```
var dropdownToggle = "<span class='btn-sm btn btn-default toggle-submenu'>+</span>";
var openSubmenu = "<span class='btn-sm btn btn-default open-submenu'>></span>";
$( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).after( dropdownToggle );
$( '.menu-item-has-children > ul > .menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > ul > .page_item_has_children > a' ).after( openSubmenu );

$("body").on('click', ".toggle-submenu", function() {
    $(".mobile-menu-wrapper").find(".sub-menu").slideUp().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").slideToggle().addClass("active");
    $(".mobile-menu-wrapper").parent().find("ul li ul li ul").hide();
    //$(this).parent().parent().find(".sub-menu").not(this+" .sub-menu").slideToggle().removeClass("active");
});
$("body").on('click', ".open-submenu", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub-menu").animate({width: 'hide'}).addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").animate({width: 'toggle'}).addClass("active");
});
```

What I want to do is when I click to open a sub menu it should close all other sub menu and open the one I clicked on. 
This is working fine but the problem here is When I click the same menu Item after it has been opened it doesn't close.

Comment: maybe do the code of adding the active class before you remove the active class.

Comment: if I remove this `$(".mobile-menu-wrapper").find(".sub-menu").slideUp().removeClass("active");` then this will not serve my purpose to close all other menus when a submenu is opened. but this line is causing the problem. I want to implement two contradictory functionalities at once

Comment: Not the cleanest but you can do an if else. If has the class of active then remove it. if not remove active from existing and add it to the current one.